# Issue with Google Nearby API after Master stops Advertising when Client connects

Tags: android, android-bluetooth, google-nearby

I read a lot of posts with 8007: STATUS_BLUETOOTH_ERROR at Google Nearby API, but didn't find the similar to my issue.

I have 2 apps:

1. Master.
   It starts Nearby Advertising on start. Sometime, it sends a short messages to clients (not more than 100 bytes)
2. Client.
   It starts Nearby Discovery on start. It stops discovery and starts advertising  after successfully connection to the master device or to the another Client device (Parent device). This app retranslate received messages from Parent connection to all other client connections.
   So. It looks like a Tree with a Master as Root.

All works perfect except the next:
Client app calls requestConnection, but Parent app stops Advertising at this moment. Client app returns 8007: STATUS_BLUETOOTH_ERROR after timeout and returns this error on any connection request during 1-3 minutes. After this it begins to work as expected and connects ok to any Parent device until next issue with stop advertising on connection request. I tried to programmatically disable/enable Bluetooth adapter after error but without success. App doesn't work during 1-3 minutes and continue work well after.
I got this issue even with two devices: Master+Client. Client starts to receive 8007 error in 90% after i stop the Master app after Client called the requestConnection but until acceptConnection
Tried with 16.0.0 and 12.0.0 libraries. No difference.

Do anybody have the same issue? Did you solve it?